# Is it possible to replicate web traffic using blazemeter jmeter using server request logs?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, blazemeter, web-traffic

I have a bunch of server logs with api requests I'd like to replicate for testing. Is there an easy way to "export" those logs {uri: $path, query: $queryparams} as input for blazemeter to test?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter is open source.  Just modify the source to replay the logs and to handle the user input and dynamic components.  Every time you see a new source IP, fork a new thread.  Use the delays between requests to define the think time.  And you will have created "Web replay," the equivalent of Oracle's DB Replay

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance that JMeter's [Access Log Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler) will work for you if your server is in: Tomcat, Resin, Weblogic, and SunOne.

If it's not you might need to convert the log to the supported format or implement your own versions of [LogParser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/LogParser.html) and [Generator](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/accesslog/Generator.html)

More information: [The JMeter Access Log Sampler - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-access-log-sampler-a-guide)